# Showing that non-diagonalizable matrix is similar to upper triangle matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following task:

> Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_3(K)$ be a non-diagonalizable matrix where $K$
>   is a field and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
>   $c_A(\lambda)=-(\lambda-\lambda_1)^2(\lambda-\lambda_2)$, where
>   $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in K$ and $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$.
>
> a) Show that $A=RBR^{-1}$ where $R$ is invertible matrix and
>    $B=\left(\begin{array} (\lambda_1 & a & b\\ 0 & \lambda_1 & c\\ 0 & 0
>  & \lambda_2\end{array}\right)$, where $a\neq 0$.
>
> b) Show that the matrix $M=(A-\lambda_1I)(A-\lambda_2I)\in \langle
>  A\rangle$ is nilpotent and $\neq O$, where $\langle A\rangle =
>  \{p(A)=c_0A^k+\cdots c_{k-1}A+c_kI\mid c_i\in K\}$.

I know that in $a)$ the matrix $A$ is similar with an upper triangle matrix but how do I show that $a\neq 0$?

What is the key point in $b)$?

Thank you!

Comment: In the first part, the argument that $a\neq 0$ hinges on $A$ *not* being diagonalizable.  Hence the completion of the proof could be to show that $a=0$ implies the upper triangular matrix $B$ is diagonalizable (so that $A$ is diagonalizable as well).

Comment: Appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), note that $A$ is not diagonalizable, and so $a\not=0$. Otherwise you would have a nontrivial Jordan canonical form, that is, a Jordan canonical form with at least one nonzero entry above the main diagonal that cannot be removed, in this case coming from the block $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\lambda_1& a\\0&\lambda_1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

For (b), simply compute. Note that
$$
M=\left(\begin{array} (0 & a & b\\ 0 &0 & c\\ 0 & 0
 & \lambda_2-\lambda_1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array} (\lambda_1-\lambda_2 & a & b\\ 0 & \lambda_1-\lambda_2 & c\\ 0 & 0
 & 0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array} (0 & a(\lambda_1-\lambda_2) & ac\\ 0 & 0 & c\\ 0 & 0
 & 0\end{array}\right).
$$